# Inequality: powers of small numbers

Tags: inequality

If $\epsilon \approx 0 $ then which one is greater $1-\epsilon^{k}$ or $(1-\epsilon)^{k}$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing bit @Babak S. Have added the information

Comment: Assuming $k\in\mathbb{N}$, expanding the second term gives: $1-k\epsilon+\mathcal{o}(\epsilon)$... thus

Comment: $1-\epsilon^k $ is greater. $(1-e)^k = 1 - ke + {k \choose 2}e^2-...... $  Can you see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k=1$ the two expression are clearly equal.

If $k\geq 2$, using the binomial theorem, we find that
$$(1+\epsilon)^k=1-k\epsilon+\mathcal{o}(\epsilon).$$
Where we have used that if $k\ge2$, $\epsilon^k=\mathcal{o}(\epsilon)$. By the same reason the other expression is of the form
$$1+\mathcal{o}(\epsilon).$$
Thus, because of this asymptotic behavior, for small $\epsilon$ the first expression will be smaller.

Rmk: Check out @DeepSee's answer, it is quite nice how he manages to quantify explicitly the inequality.

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it just uses the binomial theorem without calculus

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\epsilon > 0, k \in \mathbb{N}\implies f(\epsilon) = 1-\epsilon^k - (1-\epsilon)^k\implies f'(\epsilon) = -k\epsilon^{k-1}+k(1-\epsilon)^{k-1}> 0$ since $\epsilon \approx 0\implies \epsilon < \frac{1}{2}\implies 1-\epsilon > \epsilon\implies f'(\epsilon) > 0\implies f(\epsilon) > f(0)=0\implies 1-\epsilon^k > (1-\epsilon)^k$.

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as DeepSea's answer, consider $$f(x) = 1-x^k - (1-x)^k$$ $$f'(x)=k (1-x)^{k-1}-k x^{k-1}$$ $$f''(x)=-(k-1) k \left(x^{k-2}+(1-x)^{k-2}\right)$$ The first derivative cancels at $x=\frac 12$ for which $$f\left(\frac 12\right)=1-2^{1-k}\qquad , \qquad f''\left(\frac 12\right)=-2^{3-k} (k-1) k$$ The second derivative shows that this is a maximum the value of which being always positive if $k>1$.

So, for **any** $0 <x<1$ and $k >1$, we always have $$1-x^k > (1-x)^k$$

Answer (score 0):

If we take that $a \approx 0$ and $a>0$ and $k \geq 2$ and suppose that $(1-a)^k \geq 1-a^k$ then we arrive at $(1-a)^k \geq (1-a)(1+a+...+a^{k-1)}$ from which it follows that $(1-a)^{k-1} \geq 1+a+...+a^{k-1}$ which is clearly false because the left hand side is less than one and the right hand side is greater than one so we arrived at the contradiction so we have $(1-a)^k<1-a^k$.